# How to ssh in a non-interactive bash script with the password

Tags: bash, shell

I need to ssh into a few remote hosts to find some information. I want to run a small bash script that I can run from my work mac.

the problem is I can't download `sshpass` to pass the password like this

`sshpass -p your_password ssh user@hostname`

so I am thinking somehow I need to pass my plain text password in the connecting string. I googled quite a bit but could not find much. May be I am missing something.

is there anyway that I can pass password in while ssh'ing? 
something like this

`ssh -pw 'mypassword' user@host`

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why can't you use keys to authenticate instead?

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` is definitely your best bet

Comment: yea I tried doing that too, but it still asked me to enter password interactively when I did. Here is what I did `ssh-copy-id userid@hostname` and then ran the script. Is there any better way?

Comment: You can use key based authentication for this. Google for it and you'll find instructions how to create ssh keys and use them.

Comment: @jeremysprofile if you have some sample code that I can use?

Comment: [BashFAQ #69](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/069) is a good place to start.

Comment: ...see also the answers that involve `ssh-keygen` in the linked duplicate.